# Convert 2 column dataframe into completed binary matrix

Tags: r

Say I have this dataframe:

```
       id  time
1       A     1
2       D     1
3       E     3
4       H     1
5       I     4
6       J     3
7       L     4
8       M     5
9       N     6
10      O     5
11      P     6
12      Q     7
13      R     7
14      S     2
15      T     6
16      U     8
17      V     4
18      W     2
```

I wish to convert this into a binary matrix with 8 rows and 18 columns (the number of ids in the dataframe).  The matrix should start with all zeros. The value in 'time' refers to the first row in which a '1' can appear for each column (the order of the letter referring to the number of the column, so ub this case A=1, D=2, H=4 etc.).  After a 1 has appeared in a column it should be auto-filled all the way to row 8.

I came up with this unwieldy code which works  but it involves a loop and I have to think that I am missing a more elegant solution.

```
tmp1 <- unlist(tmp$time)
out <-  matrix(0, nrow(tmp), 8)
for(i in 1:nrow(tmp)){ out[i,tmp1[i]]<-1}
out <- apply(out,1,cumsum)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18]
[1,]    1    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
[2,]    1    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     1
[3,]    1    1    1    1    0    1    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     1
[4,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    0    0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     1
[5,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     1
[6,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1     0     0     1     1     0     1     1
[7,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     1     1
[8,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data:

```
tmp <- data.frame(id = c("A", "D", "E", "H", "I", "J", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W"),
                  time = c(1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 6L, 8L, 4L, 2L),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Slightly simpler:

```
out2 <- sapply(tmp$time, function(i) c(rep(0, i-1), rep(1,8-i+1)))
```

which is identical to your output (and a little faster).

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach sing my `mtabulate` from **qdapTools**:

```
library(qdapTools)
t(mtabulate(lapply(split(dat$time, dat$id), `:`, length(unique(dat$time)))))

##   A D E H I J L M N O P Q R S T U V W
## 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
## 2 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
## 3 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
## 4 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1
## 5 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1
## 6 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1
## 7 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1
## 8 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```