# Convert dataframe into binary matrix with rownames using R qdapTools

Tags: r

I have a 2 column df and want to convert it into a binary matrix. As suggested here - [Convert 2 column dataframe into completed binary matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36381402/convert-2-column-dataframe-into-completed-binary-matrix), I tried using -

```
library(qdapTools)

X <- t(mtabulate(lapply(split(df$V2, df$V1), `:`, length(unique(df$V2)))))
```

It worked as I wanted it to but I could not get it to print the row names.

Input -

```
Gene  Patient

Gene1 1

Gene2 2
```

Output -

```
Gene1 Gene2

0      1

1      1
```

Desired output -

```
Patient Gene1 Gene2

1       0      1

2       1      1
```

Comment: You can do this with `dcast` i.e. `dcast(df, Patient~Gene, length)`

Comment: Probably `with(df, table(patient, gene))`.